# Finding companies appearing with different IDs in MS Excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns in my data:

- `A` - each company's unique ID.
- `B` - the company name that corresponds to the respective ID.

This type of data extends to 13,000 rows. For instance:

```
Col A  Col B
12     Google Inc
12     The Google
14     Google
18     Amazon
18     Amazon
21     Amazon INC
18     Amazon
...
```

As you can see from the example above, the issue is that sometimes the company has a different ID appearing. Furthermore, although in all 3 cases, the company is still the same, the fact that they've been worded differently makes it hard to do an exact match.

My goal in this exercise is two-fold:

- Find which companies have different IDs showing.
- Identify the row at which this happens.

It would be cumbersome to go through all 13,000 rows. What Excel formulas would do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pivot tables to count how many duplicates each name has.

I would also:

Order the list by column B.
Add a formula in column c that compares the formula row with the previous row.

For example consider a formula in row 5:

```
=IF(B4=B5,"Identical","Different")
```

You could build in more intelligence for example compare the first word in the name in row 5 to see if it is in the row 4 name. eg

```
=IF(  iserror(  find(  LEFT(B5,FIND(" ",B5,1)-1)  ,B4,1)  )
   ,""
   ,"Similar")
```

You could combine the above tow into a single function, or may use both in different columns (which is easier)

PART 2:

The data must be ordered by column B!

So using the above logic to compare the IDs you should add another column (column F) with this formula

```
= find(  LEFT(B5,FIND(" ",B5,1)-1)  ,B4,1)
```

Then add another column (column G)

```
=IF(B4=B5
   , B5
   , IF(  iserror(F5)  )
       ,""
       , F5   )
   )
```

This results in a value in column G which is either the identical company name or the first word of a company that has a matching name.

You can then add another column (column H)  which compares the id's of rows with the same IDs

```
=IF(F4=F5
    , IF(A4<>A5, "Different IDS, "Ok IDs")
    , "First row in company group"
   )
```

Comment: Thank you Harvey. My data, however, is not uniformly distributed i.e. the range of rows, that each company appears in, is from 1 to 5. The formula that you mention might only look at the first 2 or 3 rows. Is there a way u think I can modify the formula so that it does a partial match of my company name with the full 13000 row arrays, and identifies the row where the company ID is different? 

I have been asked not to use pivot table for this...

Thanks!

Comment: See PART 2 of my answer.  I don't understand how you statement "My data, however, is not uniformly distributed i.e. the range of rows, that each company appears in, is from 1 to 5."  stops the solution I presented from working?   Please explain more in you question - if my solution does not work.